# cakephp saveAssociated only partly working

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am developing my application in cakephp 2.3.0,  I have looked at many posts on here and check the cakephp book and as far as i can see both arrays are setup correctly, but when it saves it only saves the first array ['TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch'] any help would be grateful.

Models

TaskSchedulerPendingEmail

```
entervar $belongsTo = array(
    'TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch' => array(
        'className' => 'TaskScheduler.TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch',
        'foreignKey' => 'task_scheduler_email_batch_id',
        'counterCache' => 'pending_count',
        'counterScope' => array(
            'TaskSchedulerPendingEmail.completed' => null,
        )
    )
);

var $hasMany = array(
    'TaskSchedulerEmailAttachment' => array(
        'className' => 'TaskScheduler.TaskSchedulerEmailAttachment',
        'foreignKey' => 'task_scheduler_email_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'exclusive' => true
    )
);
```

TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'TaskSchedulerTask' => array(
        'className' => 'TaskScheduler.TaskSchedulerTask',
        'allowEmpty' => true
    )
);

var $hasMany = array(
    'TaskSchedulerPendingEmail' => array(
        'className' => 'TaskScheduler.TaskSchedulerPendingEmail',
        'foreignKey' => 'task_scheduler_email_batch_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'exclusive' => true
    )
);
```

Shell Task Code

```
 $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch']['task_scheduler_task_id'] = $ts_mailout_info[0]['TaskSchedulerMailout']['task_scheduler_task_id'];
        $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch']['name'] = $ts_class_name[0]['TaskSchedulerClass']['name'].' from "'.$ts_mailout_info[0]['TaskSchedulerMailout']['name'].'"';
        $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch']['pending_count'] = 1;
        $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch']['sent_count'] = 0;
        $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch']['attempt_count'] = 0;
        $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch']['error'] = 0;

       $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmail'][0]['task_scheduler_task_id'] = '1';
       $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmail'][0]['created'] = getdate();
       $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmail'][0]['template'] = $ts_mailout_info[0]['TaskSchedulerMailout']['template'];
       $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmail'][0]['email_format'] = $ts_mailout_info[0]['TaskSchedulerMailout']['email_format'];
       $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmail'][0]['to'] = $pdf_form['User']['email'];
       $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmail'][0]['from'] = $ts_mailout_info[0]['TaskSchedulerMailout']['from'];
       $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmail'][0]['subject'] = $ts_mailout_info[0]['TaskSchedulerMailout']['subject'];
       $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmail'][0]['title_for_layout'] = $ts_mailout_info[0]['TaskSchedulerMailout']['title_for_layout'];
       $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmail'][0]['message'] = '<p>job id: ' . $pdf_form['Job']['id'] . '</p> <p>descrption: ' . $pdf_form['Job']['description'] . '</p> <p>status: ' . $pdf_form['Job']['status_id'] . '</p>';
       $dataALL['TaskSchedulerPendingEmail'][0]['error'] = '0';




  $this->TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch = ClassRegistry::init('TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch');
  $this->TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch->saveAssociated($dataALL);
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add the table CREATE statement (or the column names and data types) for both tables. Also, post the output of `pr($this->TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch->getAssociated());` inserted somewhere in your action.

Answer (score 0):

The array structure you are trying to save is for a `hasMany` relationship, but you are using model `TaskSchedulerPendingEmail` to save the array, which `belongsTo` `TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch`.

Try saving with

```
$this->TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch->saveAssociated($dataALL);
```

Instead of

```
  $this->TaskSchedulerPendingEmail->saveAssociated($dataALL, array('deep' => true));
```

You can leave `array('deep' => true)` out, as you are not saving nested models.

See

- Cookboox 2.x  | [`Model::saveAssociated()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array)

Comment: Thank you for the quick replay, Sorry that was my bad, I was trying different option when posting this question. Since you spotted my error I checked and re-ran the code ( I have updated the question) as you have said but it still doesn't work it saves the TaskSchedulerPendingEmailBatch array but not the other and I get no errors any further help would be great.